# Proving multiplication floor functions

Tags: proof-verification, inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions

If x, y is bigger than zero (I mean real numbers bigger than 0.) Then why does this always works?
[x][y]<=[xy]<([x]+1)([y]+1)

<= means less or equal to
[] brackets are floor function

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't know how to use it

Comment: Write $x=n+\delta,\ y=m+\varepsilon,$ where $m,n$ are nonnegative integers, and $0\le\delta,\varepsilon<1.$

Comment: That's why I gave you a link to the tutorial.  It's not hard.